# What is the use of MappingMongodbConverter in spring data mongodb?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I saw some code using this way of initializing mongodbTemplate

```
MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory), context);

 converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null)); 

MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
```

What is exactly the role of MappingMongoConverter in this case ? How is it different from other forms of MongoTemplate initialization such as

```
  UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials("YOUR_USER_NAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD");
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo(), "YOUR_DATABASE", userCredentials);
    }
  return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc, `MappingMongoConverter` is responsible for mapping objects to MongoDB documents and back. The different constructors on `MonogTemplate` just allow different levels of customization: use the simplest one that suits your needs.

Most users will not have the need to customize the mappers so that a simple `new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory)` is sufficient for ad-hoc, library style usage. The more complex constructors allow using customized instances and are mostly used from the Spring container bootstrap integration that will automatically pick up customizations from user defined beans etc.

Answer (score 0):

`MappingMongoConverter` in simple terms helps converting a java based domain object (usually your entities/documents) to mongodb bson format. It has all the necessary interfaces to do this automatically. Eventhough the default converter provided in spring framework suits most of the needs, there are times when you would want to customize or control your converter.

Simple usecase:

When storing java objects to mongodb, you would have noticed an additional property `_class: "full.package.name.classname"` stored in every document. This is the type information which enables the converter to convert the bson data to the particular java class format. You can control the converter to not store this information by providing a converter that doesnt store type value as below

`@Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory);
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, new MongoMappingContext());
        // Don't save _class information in the mongo document
        converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
        return converter;
    }`

Complex usecase:

There are times where you would want to work with data types that are not supported by the default converter provided by spring framework. `ZonedDatetime` is a good example which is not supported out of the box. In such scenarios, the dev needs to provide the converter that would help converting ZonedDatetime to be stored as a monogodb's bson format and vice versa when reading. Baeldung has a good tutorial on how to accomplish this @ https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-zoneddatetime